# Flask-SocketIO disconnects when running processes on server?

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, flask-socketio

I'm trying to generate a poem from GPT-2 and send it to the client using Flask-SocketIO but the socket connection seems to be disconnecting prematurely. After the button is clicked, the client does not receive the packages `'clickconfirmation'` or `'poem'`. I'm currently working around this by storing the most recent generated poem in a global variable and sending it to the client when it reconnects (hacky, but works just about well enough for what I need at the moment) but I'm wondering if there is a better way of addressing this issue?

Thanks in advance!

**Python:**

```
@socketio.on('buttonclicked')
def handle_click(data):
    print("button clicked")
    socketio.emit('clickconfirmation', "clicked")
    poem = poet.generate_poetry()
    print(poem)
    socketio.emit('poem', {'poem': poem})
```

**JS:**

```
socket.on('poem', data => {
    console.log(data);
});

socket.on('clickconfirmation', data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

**Shell feedback:**

```
WYb_MzevK5S0dGjPAAAD: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["arduinoread",{"number":812.0}]
WYb_MzevK5S0dGjPAAAD: Received packet MESSAGE data 2["buttonclicked","clicked"]
received event "buttonclicked" from pDHNdGwgSVGoDJ2NAAAE [/]
button clicked
emitting event "clickconfirmation" to all [/]
WYb_MzevK5S0dGjPAAAD: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["clickconfirmation","clicked"]
The wold'ring tide will flow between,
And the loud storm and tempest blow,
To drive us from the rocky shore.
Then, when he leaves each gloomy vale,
emitting event "poem" to all [/]
WYb_MzevK5S0dGjPAAAD: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["poem",{"poem":"The wold'ring tide will flow between,\nAnd the loud storm and tempest blow,\nTo drive us from the rocky shore.\nThen, when he leaves each gloomy vale,"}]
6ZhLxqlR87bDSIdQAAAF: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': '6ZhLxqlR87bDSIdQAAAF', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingTimeout': 5000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
emitting event "arduinoread" to all [/]
WYb_MzevK5S0dGjPAAAD: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["arduinoread",{"number":811.0}]
bWhw1hJsCA57fP6pAAAC: Sending packet PING data None
WYb_MzevK5S0dGjPAAAD: Sending packet PING data None
90Tgx41PpuTUaWdBAAAG: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': '90Tgx41PpuTUaWdBAAAG', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingTimeout': 5000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
90Tgx41PpuTUaWdBAAAG: Received request to upgrade to websocket
90Tgx41PpuTUaWdBAAAG: Received packet MESSAGE data 0
Client connected
90Tgx41PpuTUaWdBAAAG: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0{"sid":"nhCQsmd7v8ChrdO7AAAH"}
90Tgx41PpuTUaWdBAAAG: Upgrade to websocket successful
```

Comment: Is this button a form submit button or just a standalone button? If part of a form, you have to make sure you prevent the browser from submitting the form, as that will cause the page to be replaced.

Comment: It's just a standalone button with a click event handler on it.